# Excel Formula to Gather Data

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

i have this sheet in excel:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FCpAq.png)

all i want to collect is like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uy2DB.png)

i have tried index match but i dont get it done very well. i thought it needed to use vba but i have no idea how to.

anyone can help me to solve this please?

Comment: [Please post your data as text, not image](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/372239).

Comment: Its just hard to do thats why i prefer image to describe my problem well...

Comment: It's pretty simple to use formatting options.

Comment: i have tried and i just get more confused thats why i choose image... i dont see if that will be a problem

Comment: Please show us exactly what you tried

Comment: An example of what data you have and your expected results would help a lot.

Comment: **You** may prefer to post images, but we are all volunteers and, if you want focused help, then you should at least make the effort to make it easier for us instead of expecting us to do extra work. Your image cannot be copy/pasted into a worksheet. One can try an OCR program, or manually enter it. Having to do either of these is discouraging to those who might assist you. To make the data useful edit your question to post it as text, perhaps using this [Markdown Tables Generator](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables)

Comment: Having a formula correctly interpret a date when the month name is in a presumably merged cell is going to be highly problematic.  Solving this problem will require (a) normalizing the data and (b) providing a bit more detail about the scale of this problem.  Do you need a generalized solution that works over many more data columns and name rows, or a very specific solution for a specific number of names and a specific number of dates?